# JavaFX : create a custom ComboBox containing a TreeView

Tags: combobox, treeview, custom-controls, javafx-8

I try to create a custom ComboBox that will display the items as a TreeView (to keep the hierarchy between the items) :

```
Item1
|--Item2
|--Item3
Item4
|--Item5
```

But I don't know how I can replace the default displayed list by a complete TreeView. I made a lot a searches in Google, tutorials, ... but didn't find any response. Only about the customization of the line of one item (and not of the whole list).

Can anybody help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a `ComboBox`; there's no API to allow you to access the popup that displays the list. If it's enough just to have the indentation for the "child items", you could just apply some CSS to specific cells using a cell factory on the combo box. If you want the full `TreeView` functionality (expandable/collapsible nodes etc) then you will need to create your own control, wrapping a `TreeView` in a `Popup` and displaying it on press on a button, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It confirms what I was afraid. I think  I will use the cell factory to avoid wasting too much time. The full TreeView functionalities will be a "Nice to have" for later, maybe.

Comment: Creating your own might not be too bad: you would need to combine a Label (or TextField if editable), Popup, and TreeView.